# Proving SSL need

Tags: tls, sniffer, credentials

I need to prove the need we have to install SSL certificates in our webservers.

For that I've been requested to try obtaining sample credentials (in lab enviroment) during a http authentication process.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a packet capture tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html/) to search for the password string as it passes over the network. Basically, wireshark makes a copy of all the network packets it can see from the computer it is installed on. You then use various tools and filters to search those captured packets for data you're interested in.

Step by step instructions can be easily found online ([here](http://www.hacking-tutorial.com/hacking-tutorial/how-to-sniff-http-post-password-via-network-using-wireshark-network-analyzer/) for example), but are a bit too involved to reproduce here.

Comment: Thank you very much @scuzzy-delta! I've just did it. Do you know how to do the same thing but acting as a Man-in-the-middle? capturing not only packets from my PC to that webserver but also **from everywhere**?

Comment: Yes, but you have to be positioned as a router close to the web server. That's beside the point though, beacuse now that you have proven the cleartext password transmission, you have also proven that **every** router between a user and your web server can capture those packets, not to mention any device on the users local network. In my opinion you are being asked to prove too much - it should already be obvious to your supervisors that cleartext transmission of credentials is very very bad.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your server is a Linux box, run something like `tcpdump -i any -s 1600 -w /tmp/dump port 80` on it during a user authentication, and then go digging through /tmp/dump to find the credentials.